# Need to show metrics in Grafana of Java application also for Spark configurations batch applications

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, grafana-api, prometheus-java

I have one use case where I need to show the matrics of my java application into the Grafana but mine is a batch application not the time series, I have my data stored in relational DB.
How it is possible to like do I need to push the data to some time-series like Prometheus or is there any plugin available for Grafana we can directly use?

And also I want to monitor the my spark job and related stuff like a memory for drive worker, JVM, etc.

Any help or clue on how to start?

Answer (score 0):

For batch jobs take a look at [prometheus push gateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway). Basically your metrics will be pushed to the push gateway by the client (Clients are available for all common languages)

For spark jobs or java applications you can have a look at [jmx exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter).
You can take a look at this too for [spark exporter](https://github.com/banzaicloud/spark-metrics) which uses the pushgateway

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the response can you tell for MariaDB which exporter works ?

Comment: You can use the mysqld exporter. https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter/